# Locating large files (> 100 MB) in /home/ for 'cleaning'

Tags: linux, centos

How to locate large files (> 100 MB) in `/home/` for 'cleaning'?

It's Centos 6.x. I tried some commands, but they didn't work.

Comment: So which commands did you try?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Find has it's own `-delete` option so

```
find /home -type f -size +100M -delete
```

should do what you want. Just be careful about where you put the -delete option

> Warnings:  Don’t  forget that the find command line is evaluated
>                 as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to
>                 delete everything below the starting points you specified.

If you want to test this before using it then you need to add `-depth` as `-delete` implies it.

```
find /home -type f -size +100M -depth
```

Comment: For future visitors who may not be on CentOS: Both the modern GNU and BSD variants of `find (1)` (including that of OS X) support the `-delete` flag, but it is not part of [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). If you should need an alternative, use `-depth -exec rm {} +`.

Comment: Good to know! I was not aware the -delete flag could be used to locate large files... It seems I don't have any... Strange ;) ;) ;)

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU: Your point being ?

Answer (score 11):

`ncdu` is a nice interactive tool to find big files or directories. It will scan a given directory and show a simple ncurses interface to present sizes of directories. It also has a shortcut to delete a file/directory.

Comment: `find`, `du` and `awk` have an advantage of being standard

Comment: And ncdu has the advantage of being interactive.

Comment: I've used ncdu for disk cleanup too! It's just great!

Answer (score 9):

Just find:
    `find /home -type f -size +100M`

find and remove
    `find /home -type f -size +100M -print0 |xargs -0 rm`

Answer (score 4):

```
du /home | awk '$1 > 1234 { print }'
```

It searches not for large files but for large folders. In case of running out of file space I try to look both for large files and large folders to identify problematic areas.

Comment: `du -a` will have it print both individual files and folders' totals. Also, on many file systems, you need to add `-k` to make it print the size in KiB instead of arbitrary block-size counts, so I always include -k as a force of habit.